# Update webform without losing existing webforms

Tags: views, webforms, updating, chaos-tool-suite

I'm using webform 7.x-3.20 version and I want to to upgrade it to 7.x-4.x, but I've 7 to 8 existing webforms whenever I update this I'm losing my previous webforms cause of changed table structure. If is there any easiest way to update then please let me know. It'll be appreciated.

Comment: In the [comment section of the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1609324#comment-9414997) there is written: `Note that you must be running the latest 3.x version of Webform (for either
Drupal 6 or Drupal 7) before upgrading to Webform 4.x.`. Please try this.

Comment: Hi Huelfe,I tried this and working as well but I lost my permission page. It's not working, I updated drupal 7.26 to 7.39, i think that's why. Please let me know any solution. Thanks for this.

Comment: Hello Guyz, there was an issue with php variables for permission page issue. Update max_input_vars value from 2500 to 10000 and it's working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

In the [comment section of the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1609324#comment-9414997) there is written: `Note that you must be running the latest 3.x version of Webform (for either Drupal 6 or Drupal 7) before upgrading to Webform 4.x.`